# OperationalError in Django3

Tags: sqlite, django-admin, django-3.0

In my code I am facing problem while trying to add data in a table which i have created. The name of the table is Personal_Info.
[It is showing this:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IvyJi.png)

Comment: This issue happens when the table is not present in the database. Did you run `./manage.py makemigrations` and `./manage.py migrate` after adding models?

Comment: I have solved it. thank u for the info.